# Confusion and conflicts with multiple Python bins and package locations

Tags: python, macos, pip

**I hope this isn't a repeat. I've tried looking for clarity, but I'm having trouble.*

I'm fairly new to Python and used Homebrew to avoid using the system Python on Mac. I guess I also installed anaconda at some point. (probably following some tutorial)

Now when I do which for the following, I get different bins:

- `which python`: `/Users/ryangoree/anaconda3/bin/python`
- `which python2`: `/usr/local/bin/python2`
- `which python3`: `/Users/ryangoree/anaconda3/bin/python3`
- `which pip`: `/Users/ryangoree/anaconda3/bin/pip`

So my issue is that when I'm using python2, there are modules that that I can't use. If I try to `pip install` them, It just tells me they're already installed since they are in the anaconda directory.

I don't know what I don't know right now, but I'm sure there is a better way to handle this. Can someone enlighten me or send me on the right path to developing with Python and managing the packages.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `python -m pip` instead of `pip` directly.  Replace `python` with whatever Python.  Naturally, root may be required.  To explicitly set up an environment, consider using virtualenv with an explicit python path, i.e. `virtualenv -p /path/to/bin/python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stumped me for a while until I figured out one pain when using anaconda: just because you’re in a conda environment doesn’t mean that pip belongs to that environment. Instead you must run **conda install pip** for pip to be associated with that environment. Then every pip install will be tied to that environment.

You can check your **PYTHONPATH** to see the order in which the various python installations are interrogated.

Better still you should create each conda environment with its own python using:

```
conda create -n <envname> python=2.7 # python 2.7
conda create -n <envname> python=3.6 # python 3.6
```

which will automatically include `pip` for that environment.